# is there a way to generate a Content-Type header from a file extension in Java?

Tags: java, content-type

I have a Java application which sometimes has to generate a Content-Type header from a filename alone. Is there a way to estimate the Content-Type for common extensions? (e.g. ".pdf" maps to "application/pdf", etc)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, [URLConnection.guessContentTypeFromName](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/URLConnection.html#guessContentTypeFromName(java.lang.String)) does exactly this.

Answer (score 6):

Yes, via the [JavaBeans Activation Framework](http://java.sun.com/javase/technologies/desktop/javabeans/jaf/downloads/index.html) (javax.activation).

```
import java.io.File;
import javax.activation.MimetypesFileTypeMap;
...
return new MimetypesFileTypeMap().getContentType(new File("brognitz.jpg"));
```

You can also [add your own content types](http://java.sun.com/javase/technologies/desktop/javabeans/glasgow/javadocs/javax/activation/MimetypesFileTypeMap.html) if the Java built-in database is inadequate.

Edit: Jason Day's answer is just as correct, as far as I can tell.

Answer (score 0):

A hashtable you've loaded with the [common types](http://www.w3schools.com/media/media_mimeref.asp)?